# Problema com espaços e structs em C

Tags: c, struct, espaço-em-branco

Estou começando a aprender sobre structs em C, porém estou com problemas ao tentar guardar dados em strings com espaço em branco preenchidos pelo usuário. Quando o usuário insere uma descrição de produto na primeira vez do laço de repetição, o código funciona normalmente, porém se ele insere na segunda a variável i recebe lixo de memória e o programa termina.

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

    struct produto{
        int codigo;
        char descricao[50];
        float preco;
        int saldo;      
    };
    
int main() {
    struct produto ficha[2];
    int i;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    
    for(i=1; i<=2;i++){
        printf("Digite a descrição do produto %d: ", i);
        fgets(ficha[i].descricao, 30, stdin);
        ficha[i].descricao[strlen(ficha[i].descricao)-1]='\0';
        
                
        printf("Digite o código do produto %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &ficha[i].codigo);
        fflush(stdin);  
        
        printf("Digite o preço do produto %d: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &ficha[i].preco);
        fflush(stdin);  
        
        printf("Digite o saldo em estoque do produto %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &ficha[i].saldo);
        fflush(stdin);
                
        printf("\n");
        
    }

    for(i=1; i<=2; i++){
        printf("\nCódigo: %d\n", ficha[i].codigo);
        printf("Descrição: %s\n", ficha[i].descricao);
        printf("Preço: %.1f\n", ficha[i].preco);
        printf("Saldo: %d\n\n", ficha[i].saldo);
    }
    return (0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu erro está em seus laços de repetição. Todo o vetor em C começa pela posição 0 e vai até o valor definido como seu `tamanho - 1`. Ao iterar sobre as posições do vetor e buscar seu valor você usou o seguinte loop:

```
for(i=1; i<=2;i++)
```

Note que ele vai de 1 a 2. O vetor criado foi o seguinte:

```
struct produto ficha[2];
```

Seguindo o que foi dito anteriormente, ele vai da posição 0 à 1. Dessa forma, seu laço for está realizando uma iteração dentro de uma posição inexistente do vetor. Para resolver esse problema devemos evitar isso, tente substituir seu for pelo seguinte laço de repetição:

```
for(i=0; i<2;i++)
```

Dessa forma a variável `i`, utilizada para iteração assumirá os valores de 0 e 1 respectivamente, respeitando os índices do vetor.

Comment: Nem acredito que não percebi isso. Obrigado pela ajuda!! Deu certo.